how to use Jalali date in ant design date picker Version 5
I am using ant design version 5 and I want to use a date picker. How can I use Jalaliday with ant design version 5. From my latest information there is antd-jalali for this purpose but I guess it is not compatible with latest version of antd v5. When I try to render a component from the library, I get this error
Uncaught TypeError: generateConfig2[fn] is not a function

Although there are other libraries that might fixed this issue or provide similar services, I want to know is there any way to use jalali day in antd version 5 ?
(for example my months be like Farvardin(فروردین) and etc.)
